# Add a conditional CSS class to the label of the view exposed form

Tags: views, 8

I try to add a CSS class `sr-only` to the label of my Views exposed form.

In `form-element-label.html.twig` I added:

```
{% if title is not empty or required -%}
  <label{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ title }}</label>
  {% elseif title['#markup'] == "Search" %}
    <label{{ attributes.addClass('sr-only') }}>{{ title }}</label>
{%- endif %}
```

When I debug `{{ kint(title) }}` I get:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to check for "required" here, just check if the field is not empty, right?

You are first checking if a field is not empty so in the elseif the title will always be empty. You should have two ifs I for your logic to work I believe.

If not empty, do this: if it has this particular value do this otherwise do that.

Comment: `{% if title is not empty or required -%}` is from the original Drupal core stable theme `form-element-label.html.twig` file. I just want to check on the _Search_ title...

Comment: Ok, so you can try checking it with another if rather than an elseif.

Comment: @ thats not possible in twig. I get an error then. I have to do an elseif...

Comment: What error do you get? It is possible to use two if statements in twig, including nested ifs.

Comment: I think nested ifs are not working in twig. You have to do an elsif. Now I turned them around, I put `{% elseif title['#markup'] == "Search" %}` on top like {% if title['#markup'] == "Search" %}. Then it's working.